# .eslintrc.json no-multi-spaces value assignment equal sign aligned javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslintrc

We are using a pretty simple `.eslintrc.json` file, yet I ca't figure out the way of doing something that my IDE does automatically but then ESlint complains about.

I would like to align the equal signs below

```
let foo = {}

foo.one        = 1
foo.oneHundred = 100
```

instead of :

```
let foo = {}

foo.one = 1
foo.oneHundred = 100
```

Here is the`eslint` file.

```
{
    "extends": "standard",
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 4, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
        "quotes": ["error", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }],
        "no-multi-spaces": ["error", { "exceptions": { "ImportDeclaration": false,  "VariableDeclarator": true } }]
    }
}
```

Please help. ;-)

Comment: [It doesn't seem like there's a core ESLint rule for that](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11025), since it's not a popular standard in the JS world (unfortunately). Someone will have to write a custom plugin to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `VariableDeclarator` option, as explained in the documentation:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#variabledeclarator.

For your example, the indent rule could be:

```
"indent": [
    1,
    "tab",
    {
        "VariableDeclarator": 1, // <- What you want
        "ObjectExpression": "first",
        "ArrayExpression": "first",
        "ImportDeclaration": "first",
        "SwitchCase": 1,
        "ignoredNodes": [
            "TemplateLiteral *"
        ]
    }
],
```

Answer (score -1):

mocha:true is the problem here if you remove it it will be working fine.

```
const foo = {}; 
foo.one = 1;
foo.oneHundred = 100;
```

you can use like that it is better.

Comment: removing "mocha" : true did not solve the issue. I still prefer the first case, it helps with readability in the example it doesn't make much of a difference